# Anaconda Navigator Conda HTTP Error MacBook Pro

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, http-error

I have searched and read the posts for this error in Windows installations/version but have not found a post for the MacOS installation/version. Anaconda Navigator successfully installed but I receive the following error when trying to update or install packages:

```
CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

'https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64'
```

I am on my home network. Does anyone have any ideas for resolution?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you updating/installing packages? what commands produce the error?